# JSON to list of strings

Tags: json, flutter, parsing, serialization

Hi have this JSON from web:

```
{
    "trTrype": "TYPEX",
    "stops": [
        {
            "location": "STREET 1"
        },
    {
        "location": "STREET 2"
    },
    {
        "location": "STREET 3",
    }
],
}
```

I'm trying to map it to have only the "locations" and then, for each, do something (for example, print it on the console).
I tried so many ways but I always get errors like

```
String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast
```

or something else

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Pls, add your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to get access to your data:

```
final decodedObj = jsonDecode(test);
print(decodedObj['stops'][0]['location']);
```

To print all locations you can use for-in loop:

```
for(final item in decodedObj['stops']) {
  print(item['location']);
}
```

Anyway, it is always a good idea to have domain models in project. Then you can prepare a factory/helper to deserialize json straight to object. The profit is that you can work with objects instead of Map<String, dynamic>.

Comment: Thank you! I tried so many strings and the answer was in 1 line... :)